# ¿Qué función tiene el operador '=>' al declarar atributos de una clase?

Tags: c#, operador, atributos

He estado viendo que en algunos lugares se usa `=>` al declarar atributos en una clase. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Escritor: IProfesion
{
    public string Trabajo => "Copywriter";
    public string PalabraFavorita { get; set; }
}
```

¿En qué afecta `=>` a `Trabajo` y a `Escritor`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eso es [Expression-bodied member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) o miembros con expresión de cuerpo(en español).

Es una característica disponible desde C# 6. Esto convierte la propiedad en [`readonly`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly).
El compilador traduce la expresion:

```
public int Numero => 4;
```

A:

```
public int Numero { get { return 4;} }
```

Las ventaja de utilizar las expresiones de cuerpo es que reducen el código considerablemente. Después de ahí no hay ninguna diferencia entre los 2 ejemplos anteriores.

---

También es posible utilizar la expresión `=>` desde c# 7 en adelante para asignar el valor:

```
private int numero;
public int Numero {
  get => numero;
  set => numero = value;
}
```

También puedes utilizarlo en los contructores:

```
public class Persona
{
  public string Nombre {get; private set;}
  public Persona(string nombre) => this.Nombre = nombre;
}
```

Comment: Tambien conocido como Syntactic sugar ;)

Comment: @Einer: Solo un apunte, `public int Numero => 4;` no equivaldría a `public int Numero { get { return 4;} }` ?. `return 0;`?? ;)

Comment: Cierto cierto. Gracias